# How can i replace outliers with the mean of previous and next neighbour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter

I have a really large dataset from beating two laser frequencies and reading out the beat frequency with a freq. counter.

The problem is that I have a lot of outliers in my dataset.

Filtering is not an option since the filtering/removing of outliers kills precious information for my allan deviation I use to analyze my beat frequency.

The problem with removing the outliers is that i want to compare allan deviations of three different beat frequencies. If i now remove some points i will have shorter x-axis than before and my allan deviation x-axis will scale differently. (The adev basically builds up a new x-axis starting with intervals of my sample rate up to my longest measurement time -> which is my highest beat frequency x-axis value.)

Sorry if this is confusing, I wanted to give as many information as possible.

So anyway, what i did until now is i got my whole allan deviation to work and removed outliers successfully, chopping my list into intervals and compare all y-values of each interval to the standard deviation of the interval.

What i want to change now is that instead of removing the outliers i want to replace them with the mean of their previous and next neighbours.

Below you can find my test code for a list with outliers, it seems have a problem using numpy where and i don't really understand why.

The error is  given as "'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'where'". Do I have to convert my dataset to a panda structure?

What the code does is searching for values above/below my threshold, replace them with NaN, and then replace NaN with my mean. I'm not really into using NaN replacement so i would be very grateful for any help.

```py
l = np.array([[0,4],[1,3],[2,25],[3,4],[4,28],[5,4],[6,3],[7,4],[8,4]])

print(*l)

sd = np.std(l[:,1])

print(sd)

for i in l[:,1]:

    if l[i,1] > sd:
        print(l[i,1])
        l[i,1].where(l[i,1].replace(to_replace = l[i,1], value = np.nan),
                other = (l[i,1].fillna(method='ffill')+l[i,1].fillna(method='bfill'))/2)
```

so what i want is to have a list/array with the outliers replaced with the means of previous/following neighbours

> error message:  'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'where'

Answer (score 0):

One option is indeed tranform all the work into pandas just with

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':data[:,0],'Column2':data[:,1]})
```

that will solve error as pandas dataframe object has where command.
Howewer, that is not obligatory and we can still operate with just numpy

For example, the easiest way to detect outliers is to look if they are not in range mean+-3std.
Code example below, using your setting

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([[0,4],[1,3],[2,25],[3,4],[4,28],[5,4],[6,3],[7,4],[8,4]])
std = np.std(l[:,1])
mean=np.mean(l[:,1])
for i in range (len(l[:,1])):
    if((l[i,1]<=mean+2*std)&(l[i,1]>=mean-2*std)):
        pass
    else:
        if (i!=len(l[:,1])-1)&(i!=0):
              l[i,1]=(l[i-1,1]+l[i+1,1])/2
        else:
              l[i,1]=mean
```

What we did here first check is value is outlier at line

```
if((l[i,1]<=mean+2*std)&(l[i,1]>=mean-2*std)):
        pass
```

Then check if its not first or last element

```
if (i!=len(l[:,1])-1)&(i!=1):
```

If it is, just put mean to the field:

```
else:
     l[i,1]=mean
```

Comment: Hey Igor thanks for the quick reply! If im right, this code just replaces the outlier with the mean of my interval, which would be alright for a really small interval but not what i would prefer as best solution. Is there an easy way to replace the outlier with the mean of the two neighbouring point values? something like `([i-1]+[i+1])/2`

Comment: Hello, that is exactly what code does at the moment, if the element is not first or last in the array we have l[i,1]=(l[i-1,1]+l[i+1,1])/2, but if its first or last there are no two points nearby so i just substituted it with mean of all set, but that will work only for 2 values, all the others  will be substitued with mean of two neighbours

Comment: corrected syntax mistakes, now u can try to launch it without need of editing, NOTE: 2std is 95% confidence interval, 3std 99% and 1 st roughly 66%, in your small setting 28 wasnt outlier for 99 confidene interval, so i changed it to 95

Comment: Ah now I see it, ill try it in a second. What is the easiest way to extract this into a list? Should i append it into a new empty list or can i also directly "replace" my outlier values with the if loop argument given by your example?

Comment: @SBoles they are replaced already in the loop after check that they are not in (l[i,1]<=mean+2*std)&(l[i,1]>=mean-2*std) which means they are most likely outliers