# Replace outliers of my dataset with mean values of neighbours

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I previously asked a question regarding this problem today and also got a nice working answer. Unfortunately, I ran into even a bigger problem using the solution I got here.

My previous question can be found here [How can i replace outliers with the mean of previous and next neighbour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235461/how-can-i-replace-outliers-with-the-mean-of-previous-and-next-neighbour/56235796?noredirect=1#comment99095448_56235796).

So basically, the problem is I have a huge dataset (which I can also upload if that is wished) which shows a lot of outliers, some of them up to 15 orders of magnitude higher than the data of interest.

Normally, I would just filter or remove them but I need to perform an Allan Deviation with the dataset which means I need exactly my original x-axis (time) in my dataset to get correct interval time scalings.

My idea was using a replacement loop which replaces each 2sigma outlier with the mean of its neighbour. For that I first split my dataset into intervals to get better mean values which act more locally.

What happens now is that I seem to have too many and too large outliers which basically make it impossible to get a good mean value (outliers at 1e+25 compared to 1e+09 for my data).

Here is the code I currently use:

```py
def stddev_beat(beatname1, nameadevevac):
    beatpath = os.path.abspath('...')


    y = np.loadtxt('...' + beatname1 + '.csv', delimiter = ",", skiprows = 1)


    n = 60


    ### split dataset into intervals ###
    def divide_chunks(l, n): 

        for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
            yield l[i:i + n] 

    empty = []


    x = list(divide_chunks(y,n))


    l=x


    for j in range(len(l)):
        std  = np.std(l[j][:,1])
        mean = np.mean(l[j][:,1])

        for i in range (len(l[j][:,1])):
            if((l[j][i,1]<1e+10)&(l[j][i,1]>1e+07)):
                pass
            else:
                if (i!=len(l[j][:,1])-1)&(i!=0):
                    l[j][i,1]=(l[j][i-1,1]+l[j][i+1,1])/2
                else:
                    l[j][i,1] = mean
        final = [[x,y] for x,y in l[j]]
        empty.extend(final)



    ready_x, ready_y = zip(*empty)

    x = np.array(list(ready_x))
    y = np.array(list(ready_y))


    ##############


    plt.plot(x/3600, y)
    plt.xlabel(r'time [h]')
    plt.ylabel(r'beat frequency [Hz]')
    plt.grid(True, which='both')
    plt.show()
```

I know there is a lot of garbage inside but I wanted to get the original code I'm using.

I don't really know if there is a solution to this without replacing my outliers or replace them with some manual values, but maybe someone has ben going through some similiar problem.

So if anyone has an idea of how to solve this i would be very grateful.

Edit:

The data can be found using this [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sd7h5qigoqmyedg/190513_beat_wac_sealed_unsealed_2d_1724_final.csv?dl=0). [This png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyYoQ.png) shows a plot of the data of interest, while [this png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZRiQ.png) shows the maxima of the outlier points.

So my problem with the previous asked question is that the code basically works, but my outliers are so huge compared to the data of interest, that my mean+-standard deviation exception I'm using won't work.

I could probably use discrete values as upper/lower limits after splitting my dataset into intervals but I would really appreciate a dynamic solution for this.

Comment: Could you plot your data so we get a feeling for it? Could you also supply a small example of your data for us to work with? Could you also highlight (e.g. bold / italic text) the aspects of this question that are different to your previous one? Then we will be able to help more properly. How good is your knowledge of pandas? This would definitely be easier to do with pandas

Comment: Have you considered recursively/iteratively discarding outliers and computing mean and sigma until all the data fits into 3-sigma?

Comment: Can you show a plot of the data after setting the peaks to simply zero?

Comment: Also, if that's your fft, you may want to massage the data before the transform.

Comment: I need to replace the outliers, not remove them. This is due to the Allan Deviation I need to perform with my dataset which basically needs the original length of my x-axis. If I remove values I will shorten my x-axis which can be seen in my Allan Deviation. The data you can see is no fft, it is the beat frequency of two lasers which I readout using a frequency counter (seemingly a pretty bad one)

Comment: @MadPhysicist So basically these outliers are "statistical" systematical errors.

Comment: When I say remove, I mean temporarily set to zero: `y[np.abs(y-mu) > 3 * sigma] = mu`. Plot that so I can see what your data actually looks like.

Comment: You can discard by zeroing, subsampling, masking, etc. No need for messing with the x

Comment: @MadPhysicist with the above code I assume I will still get outliers, because my mu is huge for the list parts which contain outliers. Masking could be an idea I never thought of something like that